# Error on Stored Procedure temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is my SP:

```
   USE [x]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_CopyCompanyContent]    Script Date: 09/10/2012 12:35:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_CopyCompanyContent]
(
        @intCopyFromCompanyID Int,
        @intNewCompanyID Int
)

As

Begin
    /*
        RaisError If any of Odl/New Company ID's are 0
    */

    If (@intCopyFromCompanyID = 0 Or @intNewCompanyID = 0)
        Begin
            RaisError('New Company ID or Old Company ID can not be 0', 16, 1)
            Return
        End


    /*
        Create Temp Table For the Content Sections
    */

    If Object_ID('tempdb..#ContentSections') IS Not Null
        Begin 
            Drop Table dbo.#ContentSections
        End 

    /*
        Have to get all the existing data for the Old company we are copying from.
        Have to also add the Max(ContentSectionID) From ContentSection. Max(ContentSectionID) + 
        The Identity (Added further down due to laziness) will be our seed for the ContentID
    */

    Select      CS.ContentID,
                CS.SectionID,
                CS.MenuOrder,
                @intNewCompanyID NewCompanyID,
                CS.CompanyID OldCompanyID,
                CS.SubMenu,
                CS.Link,
                CS.HeaderMenu,
                CS.ParentContentID,
                CRS.*

    Into        dbo.#ContentSections

    From        dbo.Company COMP
    Join        dbo.ContentSection CS
    On          COMP.Company_id = CS.CompanyID  
    Join        dbo.Content CONT
    On          CONT.ContentID = CS.ContentID

    Cross Join  (
                    Select  MAx(ContentSectionID) MaxContentSectionID
                    From    dbo.ContentSection CONT
                ) crs

    Where       COMP.Company_id  = @intCopyFromCompanyID
    Order By    COMP.Company_id


    /*
        We now need to create a table for the existing content for the old company.
        Also have to create the seed. Same principle as above.
    */


    If Object_ID('tempdb..#Content') IS Not Null
        Begin 
            Drop Table dbo.#Content
        End 

    Select  CONT.*, 
            CRS.*

    Into    dbo.#Content

    From    dbo.Company COMP
    Join    dbo.ContentSection CS
    On      COMP.Company_id = CS.CompanyID  
    Join    dbo.Content CONT
    On      CONT.ContentID = CS.ContentID

    Cross Join  (
                    Select  MAx(ContentID) MaxContentID
                    From    dbo.Content CONT
                ) crs

    Where   COMP.Company_id  = @intCopyFromCompanyID
    Order By COMP.Company_id

    /*  
        Add Identity to each of the tables we have created above. The ID fields will add to 
        the Max of each table to mimic what the future seeds will be.
    */

exec('Alter table #ContentSections Add ID Int Identity(1,1)')
exec('Alter table #Content Add ID Int Identity(1,1)')

    /*
        Add content data from the temp table.
    */


    Insert  Into dbo.Content
    (
            Title,
            Content
    )   
    Select  Title,
            Content 
    From    dbo.#Content

    /*
        Have to the Content table up to the content sections table
        as this contains what ID has been add to the Content Table. 
    */


    Insert Into dbo.ContentSection
    (
            ContentID,
            SectionID,
            MenuOrder,
            CompanyID,
            SubMenu,
            Link,
            HeaderMenu,
            ParentContentID
    )

    Select  C.MaxContentID + C.ID,
            CS.SectionID,
            CS.MenuOrder,
            CS.NewCompanyID,
            CS.Submenu,
            CS.Link,
            CS.HEaderMEnu,
            CS.ParentContentID
    From    dbo.#Content C
    Join    dbo.#ContentSections CS
    On      C.ID = CS.ID

End
```

When I run it I get the following:

For example:

(41 row(s) affected)

(41 row(s) affected)

Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_CopyCompanyContent, Line 122
Invalid column name 'ID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_CopyCompanyContent, Line 122
Invalid column name 'ID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_CopyCompanyContent, Line 122
Invalid column name 'ID'.

(1 row(s) affected)

Can anyone see why it says invalid column ID? It should be joining and filling the content perfectly..

Comment: next time put a comment pointing out line 122, I'm not going to count down that far or paste this into an editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replace code:

```
 Alter table #ContentSections Add ID Int Identity(1,1)
 Alter table #Content Add ID Int Identity(1,1)
```

with

```
exec('Alter table #ContentSections Add ID Int Identity(1,1)')
exec('Alter table #Content Add ID Int Identity(1,1)')
```

or add to your "select into" identity column as below:

```
SELECT  ID=IDENTITY (int, 1, 1) ....
INTO    #Table
FROM    Table
```

for example:

```
 Select         ID=IDENTITY (int, 1, 1),
                CS.ContentID,
                CS.SectionID,
                CS.MenuOrder,
                @intNewCompanyID NewCompanyID,
                CS.CompanyID OldCompanyID,
                CS.SubMenu,
                CS.Link,
                CS.HeaderMenu,
                CS.ParentContentID,
                CRS.*

    Into        dbo.#ContentSections

    From        dbo.Company COMP
    Join        dbo.ContentSection CS
    On          COMP.Company_id = CS.CompanyID  
    Join        dbo.Content CONT
    On          CONT.ContentID = CS.ContentID

    Cross Join  (
                    Select  MAx(ContentSectionID) MaxContentSectionID
                    From    dbo.ContentSection CONT
                ) crs

    Where       COMP.Company_id  = @intCopyFromCompanyID
    Order By    COMP.Company_id
```

Comment: Probably yes. Does my first proposition `exec('alter...')` work?

Comment: I'm not sure where is the problem. Can you show me your new version procedure?

Comment: For me, `exec('alter ... ')` can't generate your problems. Maybe, you have changed logic? You have to verify your business data, and check if procedure returns correctly data.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, I'll have a look and see if there is anything else I can do my side. Cheers.